# Errors running certain apps under macOS 10.14 Mojave Beta 10

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, code-signing, mojave, tweetbot

`Apple Mac Pro (early 2009)
4,1 -> 5,1 Firmware upgraded
macOS 10.14 Mojave Beta 10
Tweetbot 3.1`

Hello, I upgraded my machine to Mojave Beta 10 yesterday via a somewhat devious route http://dosdude1.com/mojave/. I don't know if this devious route is the cause of the problem, but I am having problems starting a couple of apps, notably Tweetbot 3.1. When I attempt to open the app, I get the message...

[image]

I've tried doing as the message suggests and deleting the app and downloading again from the App Store, and I've also tried @tweetbots suggestion of rebooting after deleting and before downloading. I get the same error message each time.

- google search of these symptoms cropped up a lot in 2015 following Apple's failure to renew an out-of-date security certificate relating to the App Store.
- a tweet from the app's authors @tapbots advising someone to do the above process but ensuring that they are logged into iTunes before they download. I tried this, but again I got the same result.

Can I run a command to test the integrity of apps without waiting for Apple support or vendor support to know if I can fix this myself?

UPDATE: 
I ran the `codesign` on one of the offending apps, Tweetbot, and got the following message...

`Executable=/Applications/Tweetbot.app/Contents/MacOS/Tweetbot
Identifier=com.tapbots.Tweetbot3Mac
Format=app bundle with Mach-O thin (x86_64)
CodeDirectory v=20200 size=28056 flags=0x200(kill) hashes=869+5 location=embedded
VersionPlatform=1
VersionMin=658432
VersionSDK=658688
Hash type=sha256 size=32
CandidateCDHash sha256=7eb53c5bd255631bc46f3bee6965fed6de8b6049
Hash choices=sha256
Page size=4096
CDHash=7eb53c5bd255631bc46f3bee6965fed6de8b6049
Signature size=4555
Authority=Apple Mac OS Application Signing
Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
Authority=Apple Root CA
Info.plist entries=35
TeamIdentifier=9JTH7AWHE6
Sealed Resources version=2 rules=13 files=31
Internal requirements count=1 size=224`

I'm not sure what to do with this information.

Any ideas, anyone?

Comment: You can run Mojave beta on a firmware upgraded 4/5,1 [though 2 betas behind the dev version unless you are a paid dev] through the regular beta program. Then you get full recourse to the bug reporting tools too.

Comment: I've found a decent alternative in NightOwl. It works very well and is free!

Comment: This is a great question and this error will happens more and more as certificate chains, code signing and app notarization become more mainstream. Knowing how to trace _why_ the system asks for an app to be reinstalled or reports it as damaged will help those of us that don’t run stock systems or have a proper and clean os to test that app in isolation.

Answer (score 1):

Does it run with gatekeeper disabled?  If so it can be a codesigning issue. There is a terminal command 'codesign':  You'd want to look at the hashes and and certs auths in the output.

```
codesign -d --verbose=4 /Path/Application.app
```

Documentation regarding codesigning is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005929-CH1-SW1)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hefewe1zen. Please see the updated original question.

Comment: I enabled Gatekeeper and when I tried to run Tweetbot I saw in the Dock that it was repeatedly trying to start, but eventually it gave up and produced the "App is damaged" message.

Comment: Interestingly when I enable Gatekeeper in System Preferences, and then go back into System Preferences again I find that the Gatekeeper has reverted to a disabled state. A Mojave bug perhaps?